# change lower bound of an integral

Tags: integration

[image]

What should the lower bound be when using $u=s-6$ substitution?

Comment: If $u=s-6$, then what is $u$ when $s=0$?

Comment: Please do not use $s$ for both the variable of integration and a limit on the integral. This gets you in all sorts of trouble.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you elaborate on pitfalls of using the same symbol for both the limits and the variable of integration please?

Comment: @BernardMassé Thats actually an answer, thanks

Comment: @AliKıral Re: Ted's comment, it is simply nonsensical to use the same symbol for two different variables. If I asked you to evaluate the integral for $s=3$, would you write $\int_0^3 \frac{\mathrm d 3}{\sqrt{12\cdot 3-3^3}}$? (I hope the answer is no). Here, the $s$ in the limits of integration is a free variable, which can be set arbitrary by the context of the expression. In contrast, the $s$ within the integrand is a _different_, bound variable that is only meaningful inside of the integral.

Comment: Or would you be willing to write $\sum_{k=1}^k 2^k$? I sure hope not. But I'm telling you that when you do substitutions (as you're doing here), which $x$ do you substitute when you're changing the limit of integration? And there are other situations like differentiating integrals depending on a parameter, where the limit and the parameter might be the same, but you certainly don't want the dummy variable having the same name. Good grief! :)

Comment: @user64742: I said "Please don't ..." and didn't mean to "com[e] down on the asker." But my 40+ years of teaching have shown that (yes, professors write this garbage, too, sometimes) students end up confused and making errors, so it was meant to be helpful advice. Not just random pedantry. Honestly, if the OP's professor wrote the question, the professor probably does write the garbage and thinks there's nothing wrong with it. Yeah, I'm being brutal, but I've been around a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The variable being integrated with respect to cannot also be used in integration bounds. However, this should explain what to do:
$$Let\ u=x+T\\ du=dx$$
Then:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_{a+T}^{b+T}f(u-T)du$$
For some constants $a$, $b$ and $T$.